# how to add two variables in latex

Tags: macros, texstudio, enumitem, exam

Is it possible to add two unrelated variables that hold an integer value?

For example, I have this MWE

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}]
    \item this is one
    \item this is two
    \item this is three
    
\label{lst:num} % this will give me the number of bullet points I have (in this case its 3)
\end{enumerate}

\begin{questions}

\question[2] this is one
\question[3] this is two 
\question[4] this is three

\end{questions}


Total = \numpoints + \ref{label}  % 9+3 (from our bullet point) = 12 (the result I want to obtain)
\end{document}
```

In the above example, I would like to add `\numpoints` and `\ref{label}` to produce the result 12. Is it possible?

Comment: `\the\numexpr\numpoints + \ref{lst:num}\relax`? Not a robust method, but indeed possible.

Comment: I highly recommend to use Latex3 for this purpose, as it provides a logical and versatile programming interface. Search for `expl3`, which provides a 16 pages overview, and `interface3.pdf`next for all the gory details. Don't be overwhelemd, it's easier than the size of the document suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a robust one:

- the value of label `lst:num` is retrieved using `\getrefnumber` from `refcount` package and
- the value of points is retrieved using `\numpoints@exp`.

Some explanations:

- The outer most logic is to add two integers, hence we have `\the\numexpr <num1>+<num2>\relax`, where both `<num1>` and `<num2>` should be fully-expandable and leave an integer in input stream.
- Here `<num1>` is the value printed by `\numpoints`, which is defined as

  ```tex
  \def\numpoints{\@ifundefined{exam@numpoints}%
    {\mbox{\normalfont\bfseries ??}}%
    \exam@numpoints
  }
  ```

  and is not expandable when `\exam@numpoints` *is* undefined or equal to `\relax`. Hence an expandable variant `\numpoints@exp` is provided and it leaves `0` when `\exam@numpoints` is undefined.
- Here `<num2>` is the value stored in label `lst:num`. Similarly, `\ref{lst:num}` is not expandable when label `lst:num` is not defined (for example in first run). `\getrefnumber{<label>}` is the expandable variant of `\ref` and it also returns `0` when `<label>` is not defined.

Update:

To use `enumitem` option `label`, two things are added:

- `enumitem` option `ref` is used, which restores the plain format of the arabic "value" stored in an item label
- a wrapper macro `\getrefnumber@wrap{<label>}` is provided, which strips one level of braces (added by `enumitem`) around the "returned value" of `\getrefnumber`.

```tex
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\getTotalPoints[1]{%
  \the\numexpr\numpoints@exp+\getrefnumber@wrap{#1}\relax
}

% expandable variant of \numpoints
\def\numpoints@exp{%
  \ifcsname exam@numpoints\endcsname\exam@numpoints\else0\fi
}

% strip pair of braces from result of \getrefnumber{<label>}
\def\getrefnumber@wrap#1{%
  \expandafter\getrefnumber@wrap@i\expanded{\getrefnumber{#1}}\@nil
}
\def\getrefnumber@wrap@i#1\@nil{#1}

\def\enit@reflabel#1#2{%
  \ifnum\enit@depth=\@ne\else % no level 0
    \advance\enit@depth\@ne
    \@namedef{p@\@enumctr}{}% Don't accumulate labels
    \advance\enit@depth\m@ne
  \fi
  \ifcase#2%
    \@namedef{the\@enumctr}{#1}%
  \else
    \enit@normlabel{\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname}{#1}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{unravel}
\providecommand\unravel[1]{#1}
\providecommand\unravelsetup[1]{}
\unravelsetup{max-action=1000, max-input=1000, max-output=1000}


\begin{document}
  
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}, ref=\arabic*]
    \item this is one
    \item this is two
    \item this is three
    
    \label{lst:num} % this will give me the number of bullet points I have (in this case its 3)
\end{enumerate}

\begin{questions}
  \question[2] this is one
  \question[3] this is two 
  \question[4] this is three
\end{questions}

Total = \getTotalPoints{lst:num}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed that it fails when I modify my``` \begin{enumerate}```. It keeps saying "Missing number, treated as zero. Total = \getTotalPoints{lst:num}" What does that mean?

Comment: @AlanJones I've added some explanations to the answer.

Comment: @AlanJones Perhaps you can provide that modified example by editing the question.

Comment: I've added ```[label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}]``` after the ```\begin{enumerate}```.

Comment: @AlanJones Answer updated.